# Auth0: Insert email in access token/claims when calling web api

Tags: asp.net-core, auth0, webapi

Im using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) for my authentication and authorization. 
In the Auth0 GUI I have created/registered an Application(React-spa) and an Api, which is implemented in Asp.Net Core WebApi.

I have followed [this guide](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/01-login) to create the React-spa app, where the user can login to their facebook, consent and I will get name, profileimage and email. This works fine.

About my .NET Core Api: I used some other guide to secure my Api with clientId and audience from Auth0-GUI. This works, in the sense that users cant access it without a valid token. However...finally the point... When I look in the User.Claims from my WebApi code, I cant find the email. I can find some claims, such as identity (which is something like "facebook|866587657587"). How can I insert properties/claims of my own in the access token?

These are the claims that I do get:

```
iss=https://myazurename.eu.auth0.com/
http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier=facebook|31232133748888563
aud=https://myazurename.azurewebsites.net/
aud=https://myazurename.eu.auth0.com/userinfo
iat=2548855704 
exp=1580242104
azp=R34pt1pY691R1XzwKwSS5ntIiR7qXREY
scope=openid profile email
```

Comment: You can attache custom claim  in access token using auth0 rule. So, the email property should be available in the access token and can be parsed in the in the api server to identify the user. https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/adoption/scope-custom-claims#custom-claims

Comment: Ok, but I got the impression that email would be sent as standard... am I wrong here? Im thinking that Ive missed something. (quote from your link "*When performing an OIDC conformant login, Auth0 would return the following ID Token claims to the application*"